# In the Dark Knight, what is the Chechen's fate?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight

In The Dark Knight after the Joker burns the money, he threatens to feed the Chechen to the dogs if he doesn't fall in line. But after that, he is not mentioned again. Anyone heard his final fate?

Comment: He probably got eaten by the dogs

Answer (score 8):

The final fate of Chechen was not shown directly/indirectly in the movie. I think, it was left for audience to think what would have happened to him.

IMO, ***Joker's*** men would've handed him his fate, which was ordered by ***Joker***